# Select from a few tables

Tags: sql-server

I would like to get data from a few tables, but can't get the result as expected.
I will appreciate if anyone could help with this.

```
Table A:           Table B:                      Table C:

ReceiptID          ReceiptID   SkuID Qty         ReceiptID SkuID OrderNo
---------          ----------------------        -----------------------
A0001              A0001       9001   1          A0001     9001  DN999
A0002              A0001       9002   1          A0001     9002  DN999
                   A0001       9002   1          A0001     9002  DN999
                   A0001       9003   1          A0001     9003  DN999
```

I have tried this :

```
Select 
    A.ReceipID, B.SkuID, B.Qty, C.OrderNo 
From 
    A, B, C
Where
    A.ReceiptID = B.ReceiptID
    And A.ReceiptID = C.ReceiptID
    And B.SkuID = C.SkuID
    And A.ReceiptID = 'A0001'
```

I get this result:

```
A0001 9001 1 DN999
A0001 9002 1 DN999
A0001 9002 1 DN999
A0001 9002 1 DN999
A0001 9002 1 DN999
A0001 9003 1 DN999
```

My expected result should be:

```
A0001 9001 1 DN999
A0001 9002 1 DN999
A0001 9002 1 DN999
A0001 9003 1 DN999
```

Comment: [bad habits to kick using old style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 1):

Your data model has some problem, because if you expect this output, you should really be keeping track of some other column(s) which preserve the group ordering.  That being said, we could use `ROW_NUMBER` here to handle your requirement:

```
WITH cteB AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ReceiptID, SkuID ORDER BY Qty) rn
    FROM TableB
),
cteC AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ReceiptID, SkuID ORDER BY OrderNo) rn
    FROM TableC
)

SELECT A.ReceiptID, B.SkuID, B.Qty, C.OrderNo 
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN cteB b
    ON b.ReceiptID = a.ReceiptID
INNER JOIN cteC c
    ON c.ReceiptID = a.ReceiptID AND
       c.SkuID = b.SkuID AND
       c.rn = b.rn
WHERE
    a.ReceiptID = 'A0001';
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Note carefully the logic I am using here.  I introduce, by way of CTEs, a fictitious `rn` column in the B and C tables, which is being used to distinguished the duplicate records (with regard to receipt and SKU).  Ideally, your original tables should maintain such column(s), rather than needing to use the above bulky query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. I'm not sure, why you use table `A` in your example. From your example, you can get all desired information from table `C` and `B`.

```
SELECT
   C.ReceiptID, 
   C.SkuID, 
   B.Qty, 
   C.OrderNo 
FROM
   C
INNER JOIN
   B ON C.SkuID = B.SkuID AND C.ReceiptID = B.ReceiptID
-- next join not neccessary from your example, but for completion:
INNER JOIN
   A ON C.ReceiptID = A.ReceiptID
WHERE
   C.ReceiptID = 'A0001'
```

Comment: Your second distinct query can't possibly generate the output expected here.  If you look closely, you will see that the expected result set has two records with identical values in all four columns.  _Always_ test your SQL for questions like this one.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I did not see, that there has been 2 same result rows in the desired result. I've deleted the `DISTINCT` part in my answer